# Bootstrap XS version not working on phone and tablet

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing my site ([danielrojas.net](http://danielrojas.net)) with Bootstrap and have created a separate layout for the XS viewports. It works beautifully when I resize my desktop browser (Chrome) and when I try it on Responsinator.com or similar.

However, on my actual Android phone and tablet (both using Chrome, tested using the built-in browser as well), the standard version is shown, no matter what. I have included the magic viewport META tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To no avail. I am using a customized Bootstrap CSS, but even loading the official one, the same error remains.

Other sites (e.g. getbootstrap.com) work fine on both devices. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right that you have included `<meta>` tag. But it is in the frame.

By inspecting your code, Its not there in the main `<head>`. So Include it in that part also.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I'm also not sure, responsive will work on iframe, You should avoid using iframe if its not working.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As is typical, I just realized the frame could be the problem approximately 3.14 seconds after posting the question.

Comment: Mark it as answer so that others can benefit :-)

Comment: However, the frame is generated by my domain provider, and I cannot modify it. Is there a solution from within the frame?

Comment: if you are paying for domain, You have the rights to ask them to remove.

Comment: I can switch to a redirect instead of a frame. The downside is that my domain is then replaced by my 000webhost subdomain, which is far less pretty. I would like to know if there is a solution that works from the page inside the frame. Maybe replace device-width with something different?