# btn-xs class of Bootstrap v3 not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a responsive table with pagination,I'm trying to add `btn-xs` class of bootstrap version 3 to pagination buttons when `$(window).width() < 768` and remove it when greater than 768 pixels.
It's working fine on android devices but not on an actual iphone (safari, chrome nor in firefox)
according to [Bootstrap XS version not working on phone and tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883810/bootstrap-xs-version-not-working-on-phone-and-tablet) I have my meta tag in actual `<head></head>` but still no luck (this is not a duplicate question).
Thanks in advance.
update:

```
<div class="buttonPaginations">
    <div class="btn-group paginBtns PaginationButtonsGp">
        <button type="button" value="1" class="btn btn-default active paginationBtn btn-xs">1</button>
        <button type="button" value="2" class="btn btn-default paginationBtn btn-xs">2</button>
        <button type="button" value="3" class="btn btn-default paginationBtn btn-xs">3</button>
        <button type="button" value="4" class="btn btn-default paginationBtn btn-xs">4</button>
        <button type="button" value="2" class="btn btn-default paginationBtn btn-xs">next</button>
        <button type="button" value="20" class="btn btn-default paginationBtn btn-xs">last</button>

        <p>total pages :‌ ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍20</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your code..

Comment: @scaisEdge my html code is mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing it in incognito mode
In chrome you can find it under setting tab